# twig create menu items from array

Tags: loops, syntax, twig, template-engine

In Symfony 3.2 (using twig), I'm trying to generate menu items dynamically from array.

array:

```
  {% set links = {
      dashboard: { path: 'dashboard', title: 'Home' },
      page1: { path: 'page1', title: 'Page1' },
      page2: { path: 'page2', title: 'Page1' },
    }
  %}
```

Menu item loop:

```
        {% for link in links %}
          <li>
            <a {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') == link.path %}
                class="active"
               {% endif %} 
               href="{{ path('{{link.path}}') }}">{{ link.title }}
            </a>
          </li>
        {% endfor %}
```

I'm getting error `An exception has been thrown during the rendering of a template ("Unable to generate a URL for the named route "{{link.path}}" as such route does not exist.")`.

With path({{ link.path }}) I get error `A hash key must be a quoted string, a number, a name, or an expression enclosed in parentheses (unexpected token "punctuation" of value "{" in`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Problem

- Developer gets an error message when passing a variable to a Twig function.

### Solution

- Note the syntax of Twig expressions and template placeholders
- When declared inside a function, twig variables do not need to be escaped with the curly-brace placeholder syntax.

### Example: compare **Before** with **After**

#### Before

```
href="{{ path('{{link.path}}') }}">{{ link.title }}
```

#### After

```
href="{{ path(link.path) }}">{{ link.title }}
```

Comment: this fixed it, I accept this because more clean answer. @goto has correct answer as well, except need to drop ' ' inside path()

Answer (score 4):

you have `{{` already in `{{ path`.
In twig, `{{` is equal to the php function echo.
It's like having `<?php echo <?php echo "oops"`

```
href="{{ path(link.path) }}">{{ link.title }}
```

Comment: this fixed as well above answer, except you need to drop ' ' inside path()

Answer (score 0):

Your twig contains some errors, try the following

```
{% set links = [
 { "path": 'dashboard', "title": 'Home' },
 { "path": 'page1', "title": 'Page1' }
] %}
{% for link in links %}
   <li>
     <a 
        href="{{ path(link.path) }}">{{ link.title }}
     </a>
  </li>
{% endfor %}
```

1. Your array-like should be Iterable so use links= [... ]
2. vars (keys) inside your array should be quoted (because you are adding them)
3. As mentioned above near path you'r already inside a block so drop quotes (you are referring to a var) and {{ }}
4. The last "," is not mandatory (and some twig implementation consider it an error )